# funcao usando char e vetor em c

Tags: c, c++

Boa noite, estou enfrentando um problema.

estou tentando fazer o preenchimento de um vetor em C dessa forma.

```
int a[5];
void lerValor(char grupo, int posicao, int valor) {
    grupo[posicao] = valor;
    printf("%i", grupo[posicao]);
}
```

estou passando como paramentro esse exemplo:
**lerValor('a',1,10);**

porque nao funciona dessa maneira? desde já agredeco a atencao de todos.

Na minha lógica ficaria: a[posica] = valor; que por sua vez ficaria: a[1]=10;

Comment: No código acima grupo não é um vetor.

Comment: mas a variavel grupo num é do tipo char? que recebe a, entao na minha lógica ficaria:

a[posica] = valor; que por sua vez ficaria: a[1]=10;

Comment: Se a variável é do tipo char então ela tem espaço para um único caractere. Note que char grupo e diferente de char grupo[].

Comment: Qual é o resultado obtido e qual é o resultado esperado?

Comment: ele retorna um erro: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector. 

realmente ele informa que nao é um array, matriz e nem vetor, mas como resolver essa questao? preencher varios vetores usando uma funcao, sem usar if e switch.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, a variável `grupo` precisa ser um vetor para poder utilizar o operador de colchetes `[]`. Além disso deve ser um vetor de valores inteiros.

Segundo, se você quer passar o vetor a como parâmetro da função `lerValor()` deve utilizar o nome da variável sem aspas, ou seja, `a` ao invés de `'a'`.

Assim, a definição da função fica da seguinte forma:

```
void lerValor (int grupo[], int posicao, int valor) {
    grupo[posicao] = valor;
    printf("%i", grupo[posicao]);
}
```

E a chamada da função, assim:

```
lerValor(a, 1, 10);
```

Comment: não é bem isso o que eu quero, no caso eu vou ter outros vetores: a[5], b[5]...
minha ideia era que essa funcao ficasse responsavel por preencher valores nesses vetores. da forma como voce apresentou estarei criando um outro vetor.

o que quero é passar para essa funcao o nome do meu vetor(a, b...) e ela preencher meu vetor já existente. sem usar if e switch.

Comment: Não sei se entendi direito, mas nesse caso, você pode passar o endereço do seu vetor no parâmetro da função, e ir caminhar com o pointer até a posição que foi passada pra função e atribuir o valor a essa posição de memória, assim o seu vetor original terá recebido aquele valor na posição especificada.

Comment: Como funcionária? Pode postar um código por favor?

Answer (score 1):

São alguns problemas. O principal é que seu exemplo lerValor('a',1,10); não ajuda a entender o que você quer fazer.

**1) A variável `grupo` precisa ser um array para inteiros.** Se você pretende inicializar com um valor inteiro, não pode copiar um char.

**2) Você precisa passar o tamanho do array que quer inicializar e não a posição.** Se você quer atualizar apenas uma posição do array, basta usar o comando certo, não precisa de um método.

```
grupo[posicao] = valor;
```

Para  seu exemplo, bastaria:

```
a[1] = 10;
```

**3) Se você quer que o método inicialize o array inteiro, precisa mudar os argumentos e o nome.**

lerValor dá a impressão de que você quer recuperar o valor do array.

Neste caso, uma chamada de initArray(a,1,10) colocaria o valor "10" na posição 0 e na posição 1 do array "a".

```
    void initArray(int grupo[], int tam, int valor) 
    {
            for(int i = 0; i < tam; i++)
            {
               grupo[i] = valor;
               printf("[%i]", grupo[i]);
            }
    }
```

**4) Não sei o que você estaria tentando imprimir ali com o seu printf.**

Comment: Na verdade o que a função do OP se resume em: `char grupo`, é o nome da variável do vetor a ser alterado, `int posicao`, que é a posição do vetor a ser modificada e `int valor`, que é o valor a ser colocado nessa posição. Ou seja, suponhamos que você tenha uma array de inteiros chamada `vet`. A função `lerValor('vet', 2, 10)` alteraria a posição 2 do vetor `vet` para o valor 10. O OP só não soube se expressar.

Comment: exatamente.  isso mesmo que eu quero